# Github API compare a single directory between two SHAs

Tags: github-api

I'm trying to programmatically get a list of commits between two shas *that have touched a certain directory*.

Github's API supports comparison between two SHAS:

https://api.github.com/repos/github/linguist/compare/96d29b7662f148842486d46117786ccb7fcc8018...a20631af040b4901b7341839d9e76e31994adda3

Used to drive the UI comparison: https://github.com/github/linguist/compare/96d29b7662f148842486d46117786ccb7fcc8018...a20631af040b4901b7341839d9e76e31994adda3

Is there a way to add a path parameter to either of these? I would like just the comparison in the `/lib` directory, for example.

Comment: It's not that hard (once you define "between") to do this in *Git* when you have all the commits. Choose one of "github" (API), or "Git", and delete the other tag.

Comment: You mean with `git log -- <path>`? I'm running this against a large repo on a Jenkins job, so I was hoping to do it through the API to avoid checking out the whole repo. But if that's the only way to do it I will.

Comment: That's how to do it with Git (which would be the answer for a question tagged "git"). I kind of doubt there is a way to do it with the GitHub API, but there are things in there they don't tell us about, it seems. :-)